# Function slows down when working with high numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, average

I've wrote a script that instead of giving the real average of a set of data returns a windows that contains most data points. Let me show some code:

```
time.tic()
var selectedAverage = 0;
var highestPointCount = 0;
for (var i = 1; (i*step) <= maxValue; i++) {
    var dataPointCount = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        if (myArray[j] >= minValue+(i-1)*step && myArray[j] <= minValue+i*step) {
            dataPointCount++;
        }
    }
    if (dataPointCount > highestPointCount) {
        highestPointCount = dataPointCount;
        selectedAverage = (minValue+(i-1)*step)+Math.round(0.5*step);
    }
}
console.log(time.toct().ms) 
return selectedAverage;
```

First the step value is calculated by subtracting the minimum value from the maximum value and then deciding by 10. So there are 10 'horizontal' windows. Then the script counts the amount of datapoint within each window and returns a appropriate average.

It appears however that script slows down extremely (sometimes more than 200 times) when an array of larger numbers is passed in (1.000.000 for example). Array lengths are roughly 200 but always the same length so it must be associated with the actual values. Any idea where it is going wrong?

EDIT:
The code to get the step value:

```
var minValue = myArray.min();
var maxValue = myArray.max();
var step = Math.round((maxValue-minValue)/10);
if (step === 0) {
    step = 1
}
```

The .min() and .max() are prototypes attached to Array. But this all goes very fast. I've measured every step and it is the for loop that slows down.

Comment: not sure what is step?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to tell what the code is supposed to do, but the problem has something to do with the nested loops, and it *looks* like the code is doing far more work than it should.

Comment: Surely you can just traverse the array **once** and determine numerically which "step" each value lies in. There's no need to search the whole array over and over again for each interval.

Comment: Good point I could change this. But my question specifically is why some array is calculated within ±0.5 ms and others (Same length but large numbers) can take up to 10 seconds.

Comment: Because of your (i*step) <= maxValue; if your array has big numbers, that will take quite some time

Comment: The amount of work your code does can be determined by multiplying the length of the array by the number of steps between the minimum and maximum values. If the arrays contain 200 elements and there are 100 steps, then the code in the inner loop runs 20.000 times. If there are 10.000 steps, then the loop runs 2.000.000 times.

Comment: Is this due to the possibility that it is exceeding the max integer value? Or generally speaking calculations are slower with big numbers (I understand that to some degree but not that much right?).

Comment: The key is the difference between the maximum and minimum values, not just the size.

Comment: @Pointy Because of the devision with 10 the amount of steps will always be 10.

Comment: When asking about performance, and how to improve the optimization of your code, you probably want to use [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, well now I see: your outer loop always starts at `1`!  It should start at `minValue`.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Thanks I didn't know about that. Shall I remove this question then and post an updated script there? Or should I leave it now?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek no, this code has a bug. Don't suggest moving to the CodeReview site unless you're familiar with their posting rules; that community has been getting more and more irritated with inappropriate questions being moved there.

Comment: @Pointy No it's not, a bug is when something does not work as expected in some certain case. When it works as expected, but rather slowly. it's a problematic bottleneck, but not a bug.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek note that the outer `for` loop starts with `1` instead of `minValue`.

Comment: Okay. I will work at some of the suggestions you've told me so far and give an update in about 30 min I guess.

Comment: @SecondLemon just change that `for (var i = 1` to `for (var i = minValue` and see the difference.

Comment: @Pointy Awesome I already see an increase. I understand now that it is likely a array with very high values but little variance thus a step of 1. It will take a long time to count toward it then. Thanks a lot guys! Edit: Measured script. Went from 150 seconds to 10 seconds!

Comment: @Pointy Yes I understand that, but it could simply be a problem in the algorithm itself that the OP is using. For example if you know that an array happens to be sorted in order. Finding the largest element by starting at the end is much faster than finding it starting at the first element. But starting at the first element isn't a bug in the code, it's a problem with the algothim.

Comment: @SecondLemon did my solution work?

Comment: Sorry guys but after looking at it again we had it wrong. Now the average returned often was 0. What it eventually should have been: `for (var i = 0; (i*step+minValue) <= maxValue; i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your algorithm correctly, this should remove all unnecesary calculations and be much faster:

```
var arr = [];
var maxQty=0;
var wantedAverage = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
    arr[j]=0;
}
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    var stepIndex = Math.floor((myArray[j]-minValue)/step)
    arr[stepIndex]+=1;

    if(arr[stepIndex] > maxQty ){
        wantedAverage = minValue + stepIndex*step +Math.round(0.5*step);
        maxQty = arr[stepIndex]
    }
}
console.log(maxQty, wantedAverage)
```

We just iterate over each element of the array only once, and calculate the index of the window it belongs to, adding one to the quantity array. Then we update the wantedAverage if we have a bigger amount of points in window found

Comment: I'm implementing it now. I will let you know shortly!

Comment: I really like your approach. However there seems to be something not right yet. It returns 0, 0 every time. I will take a look at it myself to see what is done differently here. On first sight it should work. EDIT: Oops my mistake. Commented out the step calculation. Works perfectly!

Comment: @SecondLemon Try editing the jsfiddle with your data array and I can check

Comment: I've got it working. Strangely however the time is not that much different. Even slightly slower: 10 seconds 931.118273 ms. compared to 10 seconds ±555 ms. A lot cleaner though!

Comment: @SecondLemon If the array has 200 length, it shouldn´t be taking 10 seconds to run this code, should take less than a second. Are you running this code multiple times or your array is bigger in length?

Comment: Ah yes sorry forgot to mention. This piece of code is ran ±20.000 times with different arrays within that time ;)

Comment: @SecondLemon Oh I see. Still, my code is quite constant in time, your old code depends on the maxValue and step relation. For example with old code arr = [1000000000,100000000-10] would take a very long time to finish. Don´t know why it takes longer than yours, as it makes less iterations though, maybe the testing is not accurate or the difference is little

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different things I think of your issue:

1. Removed unnecessary / repeated calculation

Inside your nested code you have `minValue+(i-1)*step` and `minValue+i*step` calculated everytime for the same value of `minValue`, `i` and `step`.
You should pull it up before the 2nd for-loop where it becomes:

```
var dataPointCount = 0;
var lowerLimit = minValue+(i-1)*step;
var higherLimit = minValue+1*step;
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    if (myArray[j] >= lowerLimit && myArray[j] <= higherLimit) {
        dataPointCount++;
    }
}
```

2. You got severe performance hit when you are handling big data array are likely caused by memory swapping. From your point of view you are dealing with a single array instance, however when you have such a big array it is unlikely the JavaScript VM has access to consecutive memory space to hold all those values. It is very likely JavaScript VM has to juggle multiple memory blocks that it gets from the operating system and have to spend extra effort to translate which value is where during reading/writing.

Comment: Thanks your first suggestion was nice but it didn't increase speed that much. It went from 10 seconds 553 ms to 10 seconds 513 ms. The main issue was the problem Pointy found (in comments of main post).